# $R$-module $M$ which is artinian, but not noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noetherian

> As I' m currently dealing with artinian and noetherian modules, I' m asking myself whether there is an artinian module which is not noetherian.

I think so, but even after I thought a lot about this, I didn't find an example. Does anybody find one?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artinian_module#Relation_to_the_Noetherian_condition

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be a prime. The Prufer $p$-group $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}]/\mathbb{Z}$ is an Artinian $\mathbb{Z}$-module, but is not a Noetherian $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: This is also example 6.3 of Atiyah-MacDonald (for reference), although formulated as a subgroup of $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really nice.